# How to make search functionality in angular

Tags: angular

Please help me with this error I am getting this kind of object from the backend.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "623271addac895c8203c608d",
        "topic": "Liver",
        "subject": "Science",
        "userId": "6230ab6516f17ed82cbce749",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "623482efa8575c84edcdb2ef",
        "topic": "Liver",
        "subject": "Science",
        "userId": "6230ab6516f17ed82cbce749",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

I have a search function which search the topic.

this is my HTML code

```
<input (keyup)="searchData($event)" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Searchbox" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
<span *ngFor="let topic of topics | keyvalue">{{topic}}</span>
```

This is my ts code

```
 topics: any 
  searchData(event: Event) {
    this.topics = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    console.log(this.topics)
    this.topicService.searchTopic(this.topics).subscribe(res => {
      console.log("Filter Response", res);
      this.topics = Array.from(Object.values(res))
    },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log("error")
      })
  }
```

this is my service code

```
 searchTopic(data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${api_path}/search?topic=${data}`)
  }
```

On search, i am getting this response instead of getting topic name I am getting object object. i have two topic named liver so I am getting two object instead of getting the name of topic
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to get field `topic` from the object

```
<span *ngFor="let item of topics | keyvalue">{{item.topic}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to access them using the `.key` and `.value` when you use the `keyvalue` pipe.

```
<div *ngFor="let topic of topics | keyvalue">
      {{topic.key}}:{{topic.value.topic}}
</div>
```

Here is the [Angular official site example](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe#:%7E:text=This%20examples%20show%20how%20an%20Object%20or%20a%20Map%20can%20be%20iterated%20by%20ngFor%20with%20the%20use%20of%20this%20keyvalue%20pipe.)

I also not sure why you use the pipe either. You can just the following to get the value.

```
<div *ngFor="let topic of topics">
  {{topic.topic}}
  {{topic.subject}}
</div>
```

Comment: I used keyvalue pipe because without that I am getting that error:  ERROR Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff 'liver'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed.

Comment: I have used it without pipe now I am getting the topic name in result instead of object object but I have error in console now Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff 'liver'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed. Can you please tell me how to solve it? @skouch2022

Comment: @Calypso Could you please update your question with what you just tried? Please include the code and error messages too. This way, I can understand the issues and might be able to point you to the right direction.

One more thing, you mentioned at the beginning of your question how the backend API return, but look like you tried to get the values.

`this.topics = Array.from(Object.values(res))`. Could you also edit your question and show us the real shape of the object return from the API?